# Item rendered via a DataTemplate with any Background Brush renders selection coloring behind item

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a ListBox which uses a DataTemplate to render databound items.  The XAML for the datatemplate is as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NameResultTemplate">
                <WrapPanel x:Name="PersonResultWrapper" Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NameResultToColor}, Mode=OneWay}" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand x:Name="SelectPersonEventCommand" Command="{Binding Search.SelectedPersonCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtPersonName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding PersonName}" FontSize="24" Foreground="Black" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtAgencyName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding AgencyName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtPIDORI" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PIDORI}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtDescriptors" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DisplayDescriptors}" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black"/>
                    <Separator Margin="0" Width="400" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Note that there is a value converter called NameResultToColor which changes the background brush of the rendered WrapPanel to gradient brush depending on certain scenarios.

All of this works as I'd expect, except when you click on any of the rendered ListBox items.  When you click one, there is only the slightest sign of the selection coloring (the default bluish color).  I can see a trace bit of it underneath my gradient-brushed item.  If I reset the background brush to "no brush" then the selection rendering works properly.  If I set the background brush to a solid color, it also fails to render as I'd expect.

How can I get the selection coloring to be on top?  What is trumping the selection rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your item's template is being drawn over the selection being drawn by the `ListBoxItem`.  If you want to ensure that the color is kept, you can add a `DataTrigger` to set the background of the `WrapPanel` to null when the item is selected:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NameResultTemplate">
    <WrapPanel x:Name="PersonResultWrapper">
        ...
    </WrapPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="PersonResultWrapper" Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I was sure that it would not work, after looking at ListBoxItem's default template. But it does work, congratulations and thanks. But, I don't understand why it works...

Comment: @Timores - The thing is that the ListBoxItem has a Border that wraps the ContentPresenter.  The Border's content will draw over whatever background it has.  Therefore, when the ContentPresenter's content is a WrapPanel with a background set, it will draw over whatever the Border painted as its background.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I had misread the trigger, confusing the element involved in the trigger condition with the element involved in the setter (I interpreted the trigger setting the ListBoxItem's background to null, which is useless).